# get raw XML node using jQuery

Tags: jquery, xml

I'm in the process of moving an existing architecture over to jQuery and as such I'm using some transitional logic that I wouldn't normally use.  This codebase has thousands of implementations out in the field so I have to make these changes slowly and carefully and as such I have a method somewhere in the core that takes raw XML as a parameter and I am not in a position to change that method for the time being.  What I would like to do instead is to use jQuery to select the node I need and then pass that node into the function.  The app currently uses the following:

```
categoryNamesXMLList = feedSourceXML.
                       firstChild.
                       firstChild.
                       childNodes[3].
                       childNodes[12].
                       childNodes;
```

Obviously using firstChild, explicit index names and so on in XML is a problem and I'm trying to get rid of that now that I have taken over the project.

What I'd like to do is something similar to the the following **imaginary syntax**:

```
categoryNamesXMLList = $(categoryNamesXMLList).find("get_vod_player_info_response.vod_project.categories").rawXML();
```

the idea being that I pass in the XML and some kind of selector and just get the raw XML back to pass into the core method.  I am unable to use a jQuery object beyond this point, so does anyone know how I can do this?

Thanks,

Shane

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
categoryNamesXMLList = $(categoryNamesXMLList).find("get_vod_player_info_response.vod_project.categories").get(0).outerHTML;
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/4DKXy/1/

Comment: nice, thanks!.  Seems to work in Chrome, but not in firefox 7 (on win 7).  Any idea why not?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/hyperthalamus/4DKXy/2/

innerHTML seems to work, that's enough to get me through, thanks!